# GeoTools create feature with nested/compound attributes

Tags: geotools

Looking for a way to add compound or nested attributes on a feature. My goal is to be able to read/write a feature collection using built-in GeoJSON functionality to produce something like:

```
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "bbox": [-105.1171875, 37.96875, -104.9853516, 38.1005859],
    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" } },
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "MultiLineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [-105.0236195, 38.1005859],
              [-105.0236195, 38.0999397],
              [-105.0247731, 38.0993358],
              [-105.0260656, 38.0994475],
              [-105.0273576, 38.0999397],
              [-105.0273576, 38.1005859]
            ]
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "something": 2200.0,
          "something-else": 200.0,
          "nested": {
            "intVal": 5
            "strVal": "foo"
          }
        },
        "id": "0"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've looked at ComplexAttribute, but a SimpleFeature by definition is made of non-complex attributes. I also thought about representing the nested attribute as a Java Object and use its class as a binding for an attribute when building the simple feature type. It looks like in that case the toString() method is the fallback if there is not a Converter for the class registered (somewhere/somehow?). That however, doesn't necessarily help when loading the GeoJSON back into a FeatureCollection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally GeoTools uses the Jackson `ObjectMapper` class to handle parsing GeoJSON, with the addition of Bedatadriven's `JTSModule` to handle geometries. Currently there is [code to handle `List`s as a special case](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/a912f8ea23963c6b64b84515924dd140079410b2/modules/unsupported/geojson-core/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/geojson/GeoJSONReader.java#L495), and I would guess it would be easy enough to handle a JSONObject as a `HashMap` at the same place.

Since the GeoJSON modules are currently unsupported, you can raise an enhancement but unless you submit (or cause to be submitted) a PR there is little chance of it being acted on.

Comment: Another option would be to use the ObjectMapper::writeValueAsString() when encountering a type not explictily handled which allows a custom deserializer to be used if one had been registered for the type. A similar approach can be used for reading as well. However, that does expose/require knowledge of Jackson to the user. I have gone down this approach using a local copy of geojson-core module. In doing so, I also replaced the embedded bedatadriven JTS datatype module with the org.n52 implementation as a Maven dependency which appears to be more actively maintained.

Comment: can you raise an issue about the better dependency and may be jump on to the geotools-devel list to discuss the other suggestion